# how to remove an array of elements in a list in java?

Tags: java

Here is my codings:

```
package Controls;

// Other code

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().write("<h5 class='searchResultFramePara'>Assigned roles</h5>");
    String[] Removelist = request.getParameterValues("deleterolelist");
//String[] Removelist=removelist.split(",");
    //System.out.println(Removelist);
    String username = request.getParameter("name");
    //System.out.println(username);
    List<String> Removelist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Connection Con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    int rs1;
    try {
        Con = LoginSrv1.getConnection();
        st = Con.createStatement();
        String roles_query = "SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM demo.ZMM_USER_GROUP WHERE USER_NAME = '" + username + "';";
        rs = st.executeQuery(roles_query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String assigned_role = rs.getString("ROLE_NAME");
            String[] assigned_array = assigned_role.split(",");
            if (assigned_array != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < assigned_array.length; i++) {
                    Removelist1.add(assigned_array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < Removelist.length; j++) {
            if (Removelist1.contains(Removelist[j])) {
                Removelist1.remove(Removelist[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Removelist1);

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (String text1 : Removelist1) {
            b.append(text1).append(",");
        }

        String Roletext = b.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");
        System.out.println(Roletext);
        String update_query = "UPDATE DEMO.ZMM_USER_GROUP SET ROLE_NAME='" + Roletext + "' WHERE USER_NAME = '" + username + "';";
        rs1 = st.executeUpdate(update_query);
        String assignedrole_query = "SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM demo.ZMM_USER_GROUP WHERE USER_NAME = '" + username + "';";
        rs = st.executeQuery(assignedrole_query);
        while (rs.next()) {

            String rolename = rs.getString("ROLE_NAME");
            String[] sarr = rolename.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < sarr.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println("array"+i+sarr[i]);
                response.getWriter().write("<a href='javascript:void(0);' id=" + sarr[i] + "  class='availalbe' onclick='removelist(\"" + sarr[i] + "\");'>" + sarr[i] + "</a><br>");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

here i get the Removelist array and rolename as a request from ajax. now i remove the removelist in Removelist1 list. for example i send Removelist having one string value "initiator",then it will remove. But for example it contains "initiator","productionmanager",(i.e., the array contains more than one value),then it will not remove it.pls help me.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, you will get more help if you post a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example - http://sscce.org/

Comment: If i get you correctly, you mean you have collection of some data that needs to removed in some other(Removelist) collection. If this is the case you can use removeAll() of ArrayList.

Comment: What does "will not remove" mean?  Does remove() throw an exception, or return false, what?

Comment: for(int j=0;j<Removelist.length;j++)
            {
            if(Removelist1.contains(Removelist[j]))
            {
                Removelist1.remove(Removelist[j]);
            }
            }
            System.out.println(Removelist1);

Comment: @user3016102, does your question have anything to do with database logic?  If not, remove the JDBC code from your question.  Same goes for the HTTP code.  Keep going until you have the smallest piece of working code that still shows the problem.  If it's still not clear what the problem is at that point, update the question with your distilled code.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
for(int j=0;j<Removelist.length;j++)
{           
boolean isRemoved = Removelist1.remove(Removelist[j]);
 if(isRemoved){
     //Removelist[j] is removed
 }else{
     //List does not contain element Removelist[j]
 }            
}
```

Comment: i want to remove an array of elements but it will remove an array of elements instead it will remove only one value.

Comment: Since remove() is called over all the values of array, so if list will contain any value that is also present in the array, that value will be removed. I think you first figure out what are the values present in your list.Second, what are the values in the array.

Comment: Removelist1=[ADMIN, INITIATOR, FULFILLMENT, SUPPLY PLANNING, PRINT PRODUCTION, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, SALES, MARKETING]

Comment: Removelist={"ADMIN",SALES"}

Comment: After remove() is called on RemoveList1. still these two values(in Removelist[]) are not removed from RemoveList1 ?